# High-speed sorted insert into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

I have an AngularJS-based web application that shows a list of log messages via `ng-repeat`. Within this `ng-repeat` I only use `{{}}` binding expressions, no two-way binding. Hence this should be quite fast.

The log messages are being sent to the web application via http, and the web server sends them to the frontend using Socket.io. Basically, this works fine.

Now, sometimes some of the log messages are being transferred faster than others, so they do not appear in the exact correct order: Most of the messages are correct, but some of them aren't.

E.g., you might get log messages 1, 2, 3, 5, 4 and then 6. So 4 and 5 have the wrong order.

Now I would like to show these log messages in the correct order in the AngularJS app. The easiest way to do this is to use an `orderBy` filter, but that slows down the web application severely.

So I though that it might be easiest to already do a sorted insert: As the list is append-only, this should be no big deal, and as the list is almost sorted, it should only affect the very top of the list.

Now my question is how one could do this, in a most efficient way?

Actually, I need to sort by two criterias: First, each log message has a timestamp, but if two timestamps equal each other, the second thing is an increasing uuid. So, e.g., sort order should be:

```
10:22pm 6 blah
10:21pm 5 foo
10:21pm 4 bar
[...]
```

As you can see, the messages are sorted in reverse order by timestamp, and within the timestamp by uuid (of course I shortened the shown values a little bit).

Please note that it's *NOT* enough to only sort by uuid, as multiple runs of the logging application always start at message uuid 0, hence the list may have a single id more than once.

Of course, the easiest way would be to iterate through the array until you find an item with a timestamp less than the one of the item you'd like to insert, and then do the same thing with the id. But perhaps there is a better, i.e. more performant approach.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: If you know the array is in order (i.e. it starts empty, or correctly-ordered at application initialization), you could use a binary-search algorithm to insert records into the array. You could bias the beginning of your search toward one end of the array or other based on the nature of the data you tend to receive from the server.

Comment: Hm, I'm not totally convinced. In know how fast binary search is - but new elements won't happen to be anywhere in the list. It's just in the first few rows … hence, if we have lots of records, binary search may produce unneeded search effort: 99% of what it searches is not the right place anyway. Wouldn't searching right from the beginning speed up things?

Comment: Which is why I suggested biasing the initial search point; instead of dividing the array in half and starting there, place your fulcrum somewhere near the first 10% of the array. You'll get worse performance if it's outside the first 10%, but that should be reasonably unlikely.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that. Of course you are right, and that's a great idea, thanks :-)! If you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.